# Camera follows but is stuck on the left side (I want it to be behind the player)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got the camera to follow and rotate with the player like I wanted, but it's stuck following from the left and not behind. Here is the code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject target;
    public float speed = 5;
    

    Vector3 offset;

    void Start()
    {
        offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Look
        var newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.transform.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Move
        Vector3 newPosition = target.transform.position - target.transform.forward * offset.z - target.transform.up * offset.y;
        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can get the camera to follow behind the player instead?

I've tried changing the `offset.z` and `offset.y` hoping it would get the camera behind but it only moved the camera above and/or to the right of the player depending on which axis I used.

Comment: There are dozens of scripts already out there you can copy or learn from, including free from Unity on the asset store: https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+follow+player

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, its difficult to answer.
Do you want the camera to look at the player when they move side ways and follow it when they move forward and backward? There is no information on which axis you player is on.

If your camera is following side ways, then the problem lies in the offset value, may be you are adding it to the wrong axis.

You can also do this using [Unity Cinemachine](https://vionixstudio.com/2023/01/20/unity-cinemachine/) without any code. You can try that as well.